# bootstrap is centring everything

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've got a basic login dialog box in bootstrap, which is centred in the screen and the labels are above the inputboxes. Everything is left aligned within the container.

When I make the browser larger the labels wrap to be with the text box, however they were wrapping around, so to make it bigger I changed my col-md-3 to a col-md-5, which fixed it, however now when I resize the browser, the text and button centre on the page rather than be left aligned. How do I stop this as i'm not too sure what bootstrap css to override or classes to use. I did try 'alight-left' class but it didn't do much?

To be honest, I'd be happy with then all on separate lines regardless but I'm not sure how to fix that.

[image]

```
<div class="container body-content" >
<section id="loginForm">
    <form action="superLogin.asp" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="username">Supervisor ID</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The User ID field is required." id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="username" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="password" name="password" type="password" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>        
</section>
</div>
```

a fiddle can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/bmcmecbf/

resize the output area to see the effect

Comment: If you prefer to have the controls on separate lines anyway, why don't you use the `<form />` without the `.form-horizontal` class? As documented here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your columns do not equal to 12 on any given row, you need to make sure each row is equal to 12 columns, your columns are equal to 15. I have copied and amended your column classes so that they are equal to 12. As it is the way you have it the columns will fall out of flow and wrap onto a new line which is making it look like the labels are centralised when in fact they are not; it is the column that they are sitting in causing the problem `col-md-5`. You are also missing the row class in your code that I have added. This will give you the correct behaviour/result.

```
<div class="container body-content">
  <div class="row">
    <section id="loginForm">
      <form action="superLogin.asp" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="username">Supervisor ID</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The User ID field is required." id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="username" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="password" name="password" type="password" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
         </div>
       </form>        
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want them to be on separate lines change columns classes to be col-md-12.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="username">
     Supervisor ID 
   </label>
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The User ID field is required." id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also remove the `form-horizontal` class as it won't be required.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code fixed below. Don't include col-md classes in label tag rather use in div and wrap the label within that div.

```
<section id="loginForm">
<form action="superLogin.asp" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label" for="username">Supervisor ID</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The User ID field is required." id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="username" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="password" name="password" type="password" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger"   data-valmsg-for="password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>        
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

> however now when I resize the browser, the text and button centre on the page rather than be left aligned.

**Problem:** is with these lines of HTML.

```
<label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="username">Supervisor ID</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
```

According to bootstrap grid system you can have upto `12` columns. But right now you have `15` so your divs are pushed to next row rather than staying in same row.

**Solution:** make sure to have total of `12` columns in total. Something like

```
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="username">Supervisor ID</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="loginForm">
  <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
    <form action="superLogin.asp" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
      
         <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Supervider ID</label>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="ID" type="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="text">
                            </div>
                           
      
       <div class="form-group">
           
          <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default pull-left" />
        </div>
    </form>       
    </div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the element with some inspection tool like Firebug, you see that once you extend the width of the area to a certain point, a @media query in bootstrap strikes and your element is aligned right (for some reason).
I tried text-left and pull-left, but it didn't work

Comment: There are styles within the media query that are aligning the labels right: `.form-horizontal .control-label { text-align:right;}` this needs to be changed to `.form-horizontal .control-label { text-align: left;}` and this will resolve the issue.